# Can you use projections on Entity Framework navigation properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is a question I can not answer. I currently have the following simple code snippet.

```
return _context.UserProfiles
                .Single(p => p.ID == userID)
                    .Organisations
                    .Select(p => new { ID = p.ID })
                    .First()
                    .ID;
```

This simply gets the first user profile (which pulls as SELECT * FROM UserProfiles WHERE...) which is fine. The problem is the Organisations navigation property.

I am using code first with migrations so there is a junction table between UesrProfiles and Organisations (many to many) that is created automatically by EF. I ended up with a userprofile navigation property of Organisations and an organisation navigation property of Members. So, easy.

My problem with the organisations nav property is that it's not projecting. On the select and first I am getting the following SQL sent to the DB server.

```
SELECT 
    [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent2].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent2].[ShortDescription] AS [ShortDescription], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent2].[Address] AS [Address], 
    [Extent2].[City] AS [City], 
    [Extent2].[State] AS [State], 
    [Extent2].[PostCode] AS [PostCode], 
    [Extent2].[Country] AS [Country], 
    [Extent2].[Created] AS [Created], 
    [Extent2].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy]
    FROM  [dbo].[OrganisationMembers] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Organisations] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Organisation_ID] = [Extent2].[ID]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserProfile_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

Since I am projecting only the ID should I not get the following?

```
SELECT 
    [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID]
    FROM  [dbo].[OrganisationMembers] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Organisations] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Organisation_ID] = [Extent2].[ID]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserProfile_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

The joining is correct as I expect but not the columns. I guess I could create another object for the junction table and then write the code joining and selecting manually but this is stuff that I'd expect EF would do for me.

***UPDATE***

I am just not playing around with ordering and projections of the original user profile brought back from First(). If I change the code to this:

```
return _context.UserProfiles
   .Select(p => new { ID = p.ID, Organisations = p.Organisations.Select(q => new { ID = q.ID }) })
   .Single(p => p.ID == userID)
   .Organisations
   .First()
   .ID;
```

I end up with this monstrosity:

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[Organisation_ID] AS [Organisation_ID]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Limit1].[ID] AS [ID], 
        [Extent2].[Organisation_ID] AS [Organisation_ID], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Organisation_ID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (2) [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID]
            FROM [dbo].[UserProfiles] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @p__linq__0 ) AS [Limit1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[OrganisationMembers] AS [Extent2] ON [Limit1].[ID] = [Extent2].[UserProfile_ID]
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[ID] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

But, I guess it's projecting my ids as I want.

***UPDATE 2***

With the answer from Gongdo, I updated to have the following:

```
    return _context.UserProfiles
                    .Where(p => p.ID == userID)
                    .Take(1)
                    .SelectMany(p => p.Organisations)
                    .Select(p => new { ID = p.ID })
                    .First().ID;
```

Which outputs:

```
SELECT 
    [Limit2].[Organisation_ID] AS [Organisation_ID]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent2].[Organisation_ID] AS [Organisation_ID]
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID]
            FROM [dbo].[UserProfiles] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @p__linq__0 ) AS [Limit1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[OrganisationMembers] AS [Extent2] ON [Limit1].[ID] = [Extent2].[UserProfile_ID]
    )  AS [Limit2]
```

I am much closer to the output that I want. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Single`, `SingleOrDefault`, `First`, and `FirstOrDefault` are projection methods itself. So you need to keep IQueryable until you actually need to project it. Follow would work as you want.

```
return _context.UserProfiles
                .Where(p => p.ID == userID)
                .SelectMany(p => p.Organisations)
                .Select(p => new { ID = p.ID })
                .First()
                .ID;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The output was not what I expected but it's probably better than what I would have written in SQL using a few inner joins. Much appreciated! :D

Comment: Oh right, you wanted single one of UserProfiles. Use `Take(1)` after `Where`. Is that solve yours? I hope so.

Comment: If you use the take(1) it will actually do multiple subqueries, with an inner join. I have updated the question with the query and the output. This helps a lot more, I will check it on more complicated Iqueryables tomorrow at work but for the most part i think it will solve my problem in the interm.